# Abandoning stored proc execution from another session/connection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a costly stored procedure which runs after data in a table changes, in order to precalculate some aggregations of this data.  (The SP is called by the application rather than by a trigger on the table if that's relevant, though this is not a hard requirement).  The stored procedure is almost entirely a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement.

The data generally changes infrequently (that is, the SP invocations are infrequent) but they can in principle overlap.  To ensure consistency in this case, I use `sp_getapplock` so that the second invocation will wait for the first to complete before proceeding.

This works but the wait is inefficient and unnecessary - the first thing that my stored procedure does is delete all existing (now-outdated) data.  What I really want is for the second invocation to tell the first one "don't bother carrying on with what you're doing, things have now changed - just stop running and I'll leave things in a correct state".

Is there a solid way for the second invocation to reliably abort the first SP invocation in this case?

Comment: You can possibly try to get the processID of the first process using sp_who, and then kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way that you can do that gracefully. If you issue a 'kill' against one statement you can leave the connection for that statement in an unknown state. Also, as @GilM rightly points out (+1) - the rollback can take longer than the completion, depending on the phase of the execution.

So here's a suggestion that you might not have thought of. Have you thought about using an indexed view? You can use them in standard edition, but you need to query them using the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint to reap the benefit. But, you can simply wrap that view in another which includes the hint.

That way you may be able to replace the entire process with something that a couple of really good benefits:

- It's updated for you, totally transparently.
- It's going to be a lot more efficient than 're-aggregate the entire set'.

Comment: Indexed view would do the trick, as conceptually that's exactly what I'm doing by hand.  Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to re-aggregate after *every* change?

Would it be good enough to for subsequent updates to defer to the one that's in progress?

Even if you could interrupt it, you would have to wait for it to roll back the transaction, which could take longer than waiting for it to complete.

Comment: Reaggregation after every change is required (since, as above, the output table is effectively a view over the input).  This usually only happens once a day so isn't too onerous; I wanted to optimise the case where we manually recalculate/reinsert data.  Thanks for pointing out the rollback cost, as it seems to put the nail in the coffin of doing this through explicit synchronisation.